# Pythonesque Fantasy RPG?

Tags: game-recommendation, fantasy

I'm looking for an RPG that captures the feeling of 'Monty Python and the Quest for the Holy Grail' (preferably fantasy, although if there's a system like this that is settingless or for another setting and easily adapted, that'd be good too). It **must** be suitable for a one-shot, so anything with a core system I can't explain to my players in under 5 minutes is out.

The things I'm looking for are collaborative world creation/editing and rewards for humour (so it's better to have a *Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch* than just a *Flask of Explosion*, even if they're mechanically the same, and the player who came up with it gets a small reward of some sort). Ideally, there'd also be a way for players to control NPCs a little bit (maybe tied in to the collaborative world-building), but that's the sort of thing I can add on myself if necessary.

Comment: As this is a [tag:game-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [Roll for Shoes](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/11348/microdungeons-i-roll-to-see-if-i-have-shoes-on/)

The entire system is composed of seven bullet points, so it's dead simple, and character creation is done mostly during play, not before, which means you can dive into a game without any pre-game prep at all (great for maximising your time in a one-shot!).

The game's settingless, and because players name their skills as they play it allows for dynamic interactive setting creation during play. It lends itself to comedic scenarios easily--in my experience players have to work hard *not* to be at least a little silly with the names of their skills. Since most of Python's humour is based on improvisation and running gags, the skill system should help you mimic that ethos.

There isn't any explicit reward for being funny, but it's self-promoting: if you give yourself a silly skill ("Scaring People With Made-Up Words," anyone?), then you're rewarded every time you use that skill.